# ImageMagick leaving behind temp files - is this by design or should they be automatically deleted?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I've installed ImageMagick on OS X using macports (I don't think these makes any difference but just in case)

I use the following:

```
$im = new imagick($src . '[0]'); 
$im->setImageFormat('png'); 

header("Content-Type: image/png" );

echo $im;
```

and I get a nice conversion of a pdf to a png.
Every time I do that however, I end up with a file like:

```
magick-23Iwt3tG
```

in /private/var/tmp.  They do not seem to delete automatically.

Do I need to delete these manually or is there an option I can set to have them automatically deleted?  (I don't want to end up with tons of these files hanging around)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of /private/var/temp can be safely deleted but are not included in the /etc/rc.cleanup and /etc/weekly scripts which remove temporary files.

You can either do it manually or there is a script [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040919005905173) which should do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [Imagick::clear()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.clear.php) or Imagick::destroy() at the end of your script, it takes care of cleaning up everything.

I know it is a bit of a late response to your question, sorry about that :).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own script to delete them. For example cron, or sth.
Check this link http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/4135.htm